# Determining number of custom objects in an Experience site

Tags: partner-communities, experience-cloud

We are working on building a partner community in Salesforce. There is a limit that we can use only 10 custom objects. I would like to understand the following:

How does Salesforce verify the number of custom objects that are being utilized in Partner community?
Is there a way by which we can determine the number of custom objects utilized in a community?

Comment: I have checked this link, but how to determine the number of custom objects, and what are those objects? Is there a way to calculate, some kind of formula?

Comment: It's a contractual (paper) limit, there's no automated calculation or platform-level enforcement. If they wanted to verify, they can audit your org and look at your source code etc.